# CCI scratch org management

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, cumulusci

Community!

I have some annoying issue with scratch org management with Cumulus CI and your help will be appreciated very much.

I work with *VS Code 1.71.0, sfdx-cli/7.166.1 win32-x64 node-v16.17.0, CumulusCI version: 3.64.0, Python version: 3.10.0.*

There are lot of connected orgs of different kinds but one exact org is set by `sfdx:config:set` to be `defaultusername` and `defaultdevhubusername`, the same org is connected as a default persistent org of `cci`.

So when I run the `cci` command to create scratch org: `cci org info dev` it creates scratch org on some other DevHub that is not linked anyhow to the project.

Did anybody encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly have a Dev Hub set as your *project* default. To confirm that, run `cci service info devhub`. If you *do not* receive a message stating

> devhub is not configured for this project.  Use service connect devhub to configure

you likely have a project-local Dev Hub, which might be left over from completing a Trailhead module.

To remove a local Dev Hub configuration, use the `cci service remove`:

```
$ cci service remove devhub NAME
```

You should see the name of your configured Dev Hub service (it may be `default`) in the output of `cci service info devhub`.

*Disclosure: I am on the CumulusCI product team*.

Comment: Thank you, David! You helped me a lot